# Falla al agregar inicio de sesión

Tags: bug, estado-completado, cuentas-de-usuario

Estoy tratando de agregar un segundo inicio de sesión en SOes usando una cuenta de correo.

A este correo me llega el mensaje de confirmación, pidiéndome que haga click en un link, pero falla al cargar la página en cuestión.

He probado con dos cuentas de correo distintas, con idéntico resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es que quiero terminar con el uso de login vía Google; que ya me tienen harto con sus alertas de seguridad 14 veces al día.

¿Qué pasa? ¿Tiene solución?

Comment: Estoy intentando indagar sobre el tema. En cuanto sepa algo te digo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Va a quedar solucionado en la próxima versión. Al agregar el mail, codificamos la nueva dirección en la URL, y teníamos un bug cuando la dirección de correo tenía algunos caracteres especiales (no podríamos reproducir el error exacto pero creemos que el culpable es un espacio). Arreglamos el mismo problema hace 10 meses, pero sólo consideramos nuevas cuentas (no cambios de correo). Gracias por tu reporte!

Comment: ¿Y cuando sería la nueva versión?

Comment: Hoy, lo más probable. Pero mañana (temprano) es posible. Es un poco tarde en el día.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rápida respuesta :)

Comment: Ya probe y funciona OK. Gracias